# 0 magicka usage

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have enchanted my armor in a way so that I use no magicka on destruction spells. I would like to know whether there is any way (with out hacks, cheats or exploits of bugs/glitches) to get that effect permanently in all schools of magic

Comment: May I ask what enchantments you used? :)

Comment: without cheating, there is no legit way of doing it as you need multiple pieces of armor to get 1 skill to 100% reduction.

Comment: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615803-/61594772

Comment: The exact method and gear reqs elude me, but I'm pretty sure you can get all schools to like 80% reduction or something near there, but not all to 100% reduction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the maximum number of schools you can have at no magika cost at any time is 2.

4 enchantable armor slots. Using dual enchanting and all enchantments being -25% for a school.

Comment: Is 25% the max even if you use the fortify alchemy/enchanting potions loop?

Comment: no, it might therefore be possible to get 2½ schools of magic to 0 magicka usage

Comment: "½ school 0 magicka usage" doesn't make any sense.... right?

Comment: I mean getting two schools to no magicka cost and one less than 100% magicka usage

Answer (score 2):

No, with the vanilla number of equipment slots (and therefore maximum number of possible enchantments) and maximum enchantment strength, you can only reduce 2 schools to 0 magicka cost.